# TypeError: performanceMeasurement.startMeasurement is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Error simply occured when trying to hit login from @azure/msal-react in Next 13. When I checked the error log, it's coming from core library @azure/msal-react. I also tried with login popup, but the error still same

I have code, in my
`auth.ts`

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId : "afxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx",
        authority : "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
        redirectUri : "/",
    }
};

export const loginRequest = {
    scope: ["User.Read"]
};
```

`_app.ts`

```
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react'
import { PublicClientApplication, EventType, SilentRequest, AccountInfo } from '@azure/msal-browser'
import  { msalConfig } from '@/services/auth'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { CustomNavigationClient } from '@/utils/NavigationClient'

export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

if (accounts.length > 0) {
  msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
};

msalInstance.addEventCallback((event) => {
  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && (event.payload as SilentRequest).account) {
    const account  = (event.payload as SilentRequest).account;

    msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account as AccountInfo);
  }
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const navigationClient = new CustomNavigationClient(router);;

  msalInstance.setNavigationClient(navigationClient);  

  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MsalProvider>
  )
}
```

and in my pages just simply show Login
`Index.ts`

```
const initializeSignIn = () => {
    instance.loginRedirect();
  };

  return (
  <>
    <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
      <center>Please sign-in to see your profile information.</center>
      <button onClick={initializeSignIn}>Sign In</button>
    </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
  </>
  )
```

Did I miss something in configuration or it is just a bug from core library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE:
As per discussed here
[git issue discussion](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5587) the issue was with
**@azure/msal-common@9.0.1** and it was fixed in **@azure/msal-common@9.1.1**.

You can start using

```
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.32.2",
"@azure/msal-react": "^1.5.2"
```

---

At the time of this issue, the last published versions are

```
"@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.2",
"@azure/msal-react": "1.5.2"
```

I've used the [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/) to get   **@azure/msal-browser**, **@azure/msal-react** to run my project using the source code. Worked fine. It seems the problem occurred when the code was published (bundling/ minification/ who knows etc.).

until the new release comes out, to solve the issue, change the npm packages to

```
"@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.1",
"@azure/msal-react": "1.5.1"
```

Comment: exactly what I thought before, yeah I'm using the latest version of the packages.

Answer (score 6):

I came along this issue also today. This propably has something to do that microsoft released a new version. I just downgraded and it worked again.

Comment: "@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.1",
"@azure/msal-react": "1.5.1",

Comment: @CiobanuIon Did that version work for you or what do you mean?

Comment: It's exactly that.

I couldn't pinpoint the exact problem with the latest source code when building from a local version of @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-react. It seems the problem occurred when the code was published.

Just for future reference on the time of this problem the published version of libraries was "@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.2", "@azure/msal-react": "1.5.2"

Comment: same issue. I decided to upgrade to latest versions (same version that @CiobanuIon mentions) of the msal and I see it error with this performanceMeasurement type error

Comment: Which version(s) did work for you?

Comment: The second last published versions are the working ones:

"@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.1",
"@azure/msal-react": "1.5.1"

Comment: for angular users. downgrade to  "@azure/msal-angular": "2.5.2", "@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.1"